# Create JSON file from a dictionary of lists

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have an ordered dictionary like this:

```
OrderedDict([('C1', ['<img src="available.png">', '<img src="available.png">']), ('C10', ['<img src="available.png">', '<img src="available.png">'])])
```

I want to output this to a json file, and when i try

```
json.dumps(Dictionary, indent=4)
```

I get

```
{
"C1": [
    "<img src=\"available.png\">", 
    "<img src=\"available.png\">"
], 
"C10": [
    "<img src=\"available.png\">", 
    "<img src=\"available.png\">"
],
```

I don't want the list brackets included in my json. How can I output this to a json file cleanly?

**EDIT** I was able to get it with:

```
with open('file.json', 'w') as outfile:
   json.dump(Dictionary, outfile, indent=4)
```

Comment: It won't be valid JSON without the list brackets. Can you please define your desired output clearly

Comment: But your "C1" and "C10" map to *multiple* elements. This is just the JSON way of showing this. If you want something else, it's your own made up format, no?

Comment: So... you don't want JSON? Or you want your lists to be a single string?

Comment: I guess I do want the brackets then, I'm not very familiar with JSON, I just want the dictionary outputted to a proper json file.